# How to use registry in block?

Tags: magento2, blocks, registry

I'm trying to get registry value in my block. Here's how block looks like,

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Dunning\Block\Adminhtml\Dunning\Edit\Tab;

class PartPayments extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{
    protected $_template = 'Vendor_Dunning::installments.phtml';

    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ) {
        $this->registry     = $registry;
    }
}
```

Template is getting rendered but If I create constructor then it gives me error like below which looks dangerous to debug.

> Fatal error: Method
>   Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::__toString() must not throw an
>   exception, caught Error: Call to a member function dispatch() on null
>   in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Wrapper/UiComponent.php
>   on line 0

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like error occurred from other code. Still, you can create registry like :

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Dunning\Block\Adminhtml\Dunning\Edit\Tab;

class PartPayments extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Template
{
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    protected $_template = 'Vendor_Dunning::installments.phtml';

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
}
```

**Reference file : Magento\Cms\Block\Adminhtml\Wysiwyg\Images/Tree.php**

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `Registry` in my `block` from getting the function of the `Registry` which I created in `helper` class n its works perfectly for me... you can give a try